# How to stop Sublime Text 3 from outputing "junk" when a build fails?

Tags: sublime-text-3, sublime-text

Sorry I know my question is a bit unclear but this is what I mean:

[image: Sublime Text Jun example]

As you can see, on a build that fails, Sublime outputs a lot of this so called "junk." How can I stop this from happening? This is not just a Python problem. It happens with other languages too on a build fail (i.e. Java)

Just so if you were curious, here is what happens when a build is successful:
[image: Successful Sublime Build with no unnecessary junk.]

Comment: Have you tried the [quiet option](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/build_systems.html#exec_options) in your build system?

Comment: Just tried it and it worked! Thanks! If anyone's wondering how to do this, here is a nice thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38870788/5721784